# Can't find controls that don't have enough defined properties in Coded UI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, coded-ui-tests

This may be a noobish question, but in my records in Coded UI Tests, I have recorded a lot of controls that don't have enough defined properties to be found in playback.

For exemple:

```
public HtmlEdit UIItemEdit
{
    get
    {
        if ((this.mUIItemEdit == null))
        {
            this.mUIItemEdit = new HtmlEdit(this);
            #region Search Criteria
            this.mUIItemEdit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Id] = null;
            this.mUIItemEdit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Name] = null;
            this.mUIItemEdit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.LabeledBy] = null;
            this.mUIItemEdit.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Type] = "SINGLELINE";
            this.mUIItemEdit.FilterProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Title] = null;
            this.mUIItemEdit.FilterProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Class] = null;
            this.mUIItemEdit.FilterProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.ControlDefinition] = "type=\"text\" value=\"\"";
            this.mUIItemEdit.FilterProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.TagInstance] = "5";
            this.mUIItemEdit.WindowTitles.Add("http://cms.home.psafe.com/");
            #endregion
        }
        return this.mUIItemEdit;
    }
```

In [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220334/the-playback-failed-to-find-the-control-with-the-given-search-properties-in-code/28220869#28220869), I learned about `SearchProperties`, but it doesn't look to be an appropriate solution in this case.

Is there any other way to wrap these controls properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to find it if its containing element can be found. You can use the containing element to scope the search. So, find that element's parent, then find an input type=text within it:

```
var container = new HtmlControl(bw); //where bw is the browser window 
HtmlDiv parentDiv = new HtmlDiv(container);
parentDiv.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id] = "theIdOfYourDiv";

HtmlEdit edt = new HtmlEdit(parentDiv); //the search scope is narrowed down to the div only. This may be enough to find your control with the search property.
edt.SearchProperties[HtmlEdit.PropertyNames.Type] = "SINGLELINE";
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I still have one question: Is it possible to use css selector or xpath like selenium in this case?

Comment: @andrepm I don't really know the answer but it looks like someone smarter than me knows how: http://tom.cabanski.com/2013/07/13/using-jquery-selectors-in-codedui/

Comment: @Crowcoder, can you take a look at a similar post I did? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40158387/codedui-find-lower-level-list-item-without-an-id

Answer (score 1):

You have two options:

1. Try crowcoder's solution of searching in the parent. The problem with this solution is when you move a control around you're going to be changing code a lot.
2. Add an Id property to all your controls in the HTML, this will make your Coded UI more robust and responsive to changes in the UI.