# CodedUI Find lower level List Item without an ID?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I am experimenting with CodedUI using C# and am having some trouble. I have got a `<div>` containing an ID, and then a non-uniquely identified `<ul>` with several `<li>` tags like the below:

```
<div id="uniqueIdValue" class"long_class" activetabindex="0" sfwtabcontainer="true">
   <ul class="long_class2">::before
      <li class="sharedListItemClass" sfwtabheader="true">...</li>
      <li class="sharedListItemClass" sfwtabheader="true">
           <a href="#someValue">History</a>
      </li>
      <li class="sharedListItemClass" sfwtabheader="true">...</li>
      ::after
   </ul>
```

How can I setup a `Mouse.Click(...)` on the the second list item (or the `<a>` within) containing my `<a>` tag with test of "History"?

I have tried every combination I can think of to specify this tag by itself, all the way up to specifying the parent and trying to get the "TagInstance":

```
var container = new HtmlControl(_bw);
HtmlDiv nameForDiv = new HtmlDiv(container);
nameForDiv.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id] = "uniqueDivIdentifier";
nameForDiv.SearchProperties[HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Class] = "long Multiple_Classes";

var historyTab = new HtmlHyperlink(nameForDiv);
historyTab.SearchProperties[HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.Href] = "#someValue";
historyTab.SearchProperties[HtmlHyperlink.PropertyNames.TagInstance] = "2";

Mouse.Click(historyTab)
```

Resulting in the control cannot be found. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: I don't even have Coded UI anymore (VS downgrade) such that I can test, but why are you searching id `uniqueDivIdentifier` when the id is `uniqueIdValue`? And likewise class `long Multiple_Classes` vs `long_class`?

Comment: Sorry, that was code obfuscation on my end. They do match, I just can't figure out how to get that second list item, only the parent div that holds the <ul> and then all the <li>'s.

Comment: Have you tried finding something unique about the [control definition as mentioned here](http://blog.majcica.com/2015/06/14/codedui-tips-and-tricks-unavailable-search-attributes/)?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
    var browser = BrowserWindow.Launch("url");

    private void ClickLink()
    {

        var parent = GetPaneID(browser, "uniqueIdValue");
        var child = parent.GetChildren()[0];
        var child2 = child.GetChildren()[1];
        var child3 = child2.GetChildren()[0];
        Mouse.Click(child3);       
    }
```

where method GetPaneId() looks like this:

```
    public HtmlDiv GetPaneID(UITestControl parent, string id)
    {
        var gpane = new HtmlDiv(parent);
        gpane.SearchProperties.Add(HtmlDiv.PropertyNames.Id, id);
        return gpane;
    }
```