# Coded Ui Playback failed to find Frame, C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, internet-explorer-11, coded-ui-tests

Please find the exception details.

> {"The playback failed to find the control with the given search
>   properties. Additional Details: \r\nTechnologyName: 
>   'Web'\r\nControlType:  'Frame'\r\nTagName:  'IFRAME'\r\nId: 
>   'main'\r\nName:  'main'\r\n Failed to find any control that matched
>   the search condition Id='main' && Name='main' && ControlType='Frame'"}

I'm trying to automate a web page using coded Ui, some of the controls are inside frames. I'm facing problem while taking the html document of this frame and even its failing to find the frame with mentioned ID.
I'm using Visual studio 2013 premium and c#.

Comment: Hi Geethu, Here is a [similar thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220334/the-playback-failed-to-find-the-control-with-the-given-search-properties-in-code) may be an useful one

Comment: Hi un-lucky,can you please help me with frame automation in c#

Comment: Sorry Geethu, I'm not familiar with that, No worries! Someone else from this community will help you soon